# No se ejecuta la estructura repetitiva

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, condiciones, bucles, while

Necesito ayuda con este código, no se porque no se ejucuta la estructura repetitiva. Solo se ejecuta una vez y falla.

La consigna es la siguiente:

> Desarrollar un programa que permita controlar la cantidad de vacunas aplicadas diariamente en 24 centros de vacunación. El programa le pide al usuario por cada centro la cantidad de vacunas aplicadas en el día. Verificar que los datos ingresados sean válidos (números iguales o mayores a 0). Luego calcular el promedio de vacunas aplicadas de todos los centros. Teniendo en cuenta que para cumplir con el plan de vacunación la cantidad mínima de vacunas que debe aplicar diariamente un centro es de 1000, calcular el porcentaje de centros que igualan la cantidad mínima, el porcentaje de centros que superan la cantidad mínima (cumplen con el plan) y el porcentaje de centros que no alcanzan la cantidad mínima (no cumplen con el plan). Mostrar los resultados en la página.

Mi codigo JavaScript es este:

```js
var vacunas, centro;
var masvacuna, menosvacuna, mascentro, menoscentro;
var suma = 0;
var promedio;
var supraplan = 0;
var infraplan = 0;
var plan = 0;
var bandera = true;



for (i = 1; i <= 24; i++) {

  vacunas = Number(prompt('Ingrese la cantidad de vacunas que el centro ' + i + ' aplicó en el dia.', ''));

  while (vacunas == '' || isNaN(vacunas) || vacunas < 0) {

    alert('Dato no valido');
    vacunas = Number(prompt('Ingrese la cantidad de vacunas que el centro ' + i + ' aplicó en el dia.', ''));
  }

  if (bandera) {
    masvacuna = vacunas;
    menosvacuna = vacunas;
    mascentro = centro;
    menoscentro = centro;
    bandera = false;
  }
  if (vacunas > masvacunas) {
    masvacuna = vacunas;
    mascentro = centro;
  }
  if (vacunas < menosvacuna) {
    menosvacuna = vacunas;
    menoscentro = centro;
  }
  vacunas = Number(prompt('Ingrese la cantidad de vacunas que el centro ' + i + ' aplicó en el dia.', ''));
}
suma += vacunas;

if (bandera) {
  document.write('No hay datos para evaluar');
} else {
  promedio = suma / 24;
  docuemnt.write('El promedio de vacunas aplicadas en los centros es: ' + promedio + '<br><br>');
}
if (vacunas > 1000) {
  supraplan += centro;

  document.write('El porcentaje de centros que superaron el plan de vacunacion fue: ' + (supraplan * 24 / 100) + '%<br>');
} else if (vacunas < 1000) {
  infraplan += centro;

  document.write('El porcentaje de centros que nosuperaron el plan de vacunacion fue: ' + (infraplan * 24 / 100) + '%<br>');
} else if (vacunas = 1000) {
  plan += centro;
  docuement.write(' El porcentaje de centros que alcanzaron el plan de vacunacion fue: ' + plan + '%')
}
```

Comment: Tienes un error, estas llamando de forma plural a *masVacunas*, y tu declaración es *masVacuna* singular!

Comment: Tenés razón, si bien corrigiéndolo el bucle funcionó (tmb eliminé la fila dónde vuelvo a preguntar x un valor para la.variable vacunas antes de hacer la suma+=vacunas) no logré que se escriban todos los document.write del final 

Answer (score 2):

Antes de comenzar quiero hacer una observación -y espero que la tengas en mente para futuros proyectos-. En tu código, en la primera parte de la evaluación, si colocas un `0` entrarás en conflicto debido a que estás evaluando un valor [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). `0` es un valor Falsy al igual que `''` por lo que al utilizar doble igual (`==`) lo que pasará es que JS hará un "casteo" intentando igualar el tipo en ambos lados de la comparación, al ser valores Falsy el resultado será `true` (`false == false`). Lo anterior causará que cuando coloques un `0` te diga que es un dato inválido. Para solucionar esto solo basta con utilizar triple igual (`===`) lo cual aparte del valor, validará el tipo de dato.

Aclarado el punto anterior puedo continuar. Puedes aprovechar el bucle para calcular el promedio y hacer las demás operaciones.

```js
const vacunasAplicadasPorCentro = [];
const CENTROS_DE_VACUNACION = 3;
const MINIMO_DE_VACUNAS = 1000;
let sumaTotal = 0;
let noAlcanzaMinimo = 0;
let superaMinimo = 0;
let igualaMinimo = 0;

for (i = 1; i <= CENTROS_DE_VACUNACION; i++) {
  let vacunas = Number(prompt('Ingrese la cantidad de vacunas que el centro ' + i + ' aplicó en el dia.'));

  while (vacunas === '' || isNaN(vacunas) || vacunas < 0) {
    alert('Dato no válido');
    vacunas = Number(prompt('Ingrese la cantidad de vacunas que el centro ' + i + ' aplicó en el dia.'));
  }

  vacunasAplicadasPorCentro.push(vacunas);
  sumaTotal += vacunas;

  if (vacunas < MINIMO_DE_VACUNAS) {
    noAlcanzaMinimo += 1;
  } else if (vacunas === MINIMO_DE_VACUNAS) {
    igualaMinimo += 1;
  } else if (vacunas > MINIMO_DE_VACUNAS) {
    superaMinimo += 1;
  }
}

if (sumaTotal === 0) {
  document.write('No hay datos para evaluar');
} else {
  let promedio = sumaTotal / CENTROS_DE_VACUNACION;
  document.write(`El promedio de vacunas aplicadas en los centros es: ${promedio}<br><br>`);
  document.write(`El porcentaje de centros que superaron el plan de vacunacion fue: ${superaMinimo / CENTROS_DE_VACUNACION * 100}%<br><br>`);
  document.write(`El porcentaje de centros que no superaron el plan de vacunacion fue: ${noAlcanzaMinimo / CENTROS_DE_VACUNACION * 100}%<br><br>`);
  document.write(`El porcentaje de centros que alcanzaron el plan de vacunacion fue: ${igualaMinimo / CENTROS_DE_VACUNACION * 100}%<br><br>`);
}
```

Puedes simplificar cosas y tener un código más "limpio" haciendo que en el ciclo solo se guarden los datos y luego hacer todas las validaciones y cálculos correspondientes.

Para ello puedes atacar el problema de la siguiente manera:

1. Almacenar cada valor de las vacunas en un array
2. Validar que haya datos para trabajar
3. Obtener el promedio
4. Localizar aquellos valores que superen el límite
5. Localizar aquellos valores que no superen el límite
6. Localizar aquellos valores que igualen el límite

Para el primer punto ocupas un array vacío en el que hagas [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) de cada valor.

En el segundo punto usas [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) para validar que existan datos, si todos son 0, entonces no tiene caso hacer los siguientes puntos.

Para el tercer punto, puedes usar [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) para obtener la sumatoria y luego hacer una división para el promedio.

Para los puntos del 4 al 6, usa [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) para filtrar aquellos valores que superen (`> 1000`), no superen (`< 1000`) e igualen (`=== 1000`) al límite establecido. Ya que tengas los resultados, solo cuentas cuantos son y aplicas la debida operación aritmética para hacer el cálculo del porcentaje.

Ya que tienes estos datos solo resta mostrar la información.

```js
const vacunasAplicadasPorCentro = [];
const CENTROS_DE_VACUNACION = 3;
const MINIMO_DE_VACUNAS = 1000;
 
for (i = 1; i <= CENTROS_DE_VACUNACION; i++) {
  let vacunas = Number(prompt('Ingrese la cantidad de vacunas que el centro ' + i + ' aplicó en el dia.'));

  while (vacunas === '' || isNaN(vacunas) || vacunas < 0) {
    alert('Dato no válido');
    vacunas = Number(prompt('Ingrese la cantidad de vacunas que el centro ' + i + ' aplicó en el dia.'));
  }

  vacunasAplicadasPorCentro.push(vacunas);
}

if (vacunasAplicadasPorCentro.every(vacunas => vacunas === 0)) {
  document.write('No hay datos para evaluar');
} else {
  let promedio = vacunasAplicadasPorCentro.reduce((total, vacunas) => total += vacunas, 0) / CENTROS_DE_VACUNACION;
  document.write(`El promedio de vacunas aplicadas en los centros es: ${promedio}<br><br>`);
  
  const noAlcanzaMinimo = vacunasAplicadasPorCentro.filter(vacunas => vacunas < MINIMO_DE_VACUNAS).length / CENTROS_DE_VACUNACION * 100;
  const superaMinimo = vacunasAplicadasPorCentro.filter(vacunas => vacunas > MINIMO_DE_VACUNAS).length / CENTROS_DE_VACUNACION * 100;
  const igualaMinimo = vacunasAplicadasPorCentro.filter(vacunas => vacunas === MINIMO_DE_VACUNAS).length / CENTROS_DE_VACUNACION * 100;
  
  document.write(`El porcentaje de centros que superaron el plan de vacunacion fue: ${superaMinimo}%<br><br>`);
  document.write(`El porcentaje de centros que no superaron el plan de vacunacion fue: ${noAlcanzaMinimo}%<br><br>`);
  document.write(`El porcentaje de centros que alcanzaron el plan de vacunacion fue: ${igualaMinimo}%<br><br>`);
}
```